# OpenOffice Calc move only unique values to new column

Tags: validation, duplicates, unique, openoffice-calc

I looked around for a bit and didn't see any question quite like the one I have. I have a sheet with over 80k values in column A. What I need, is to remove every occurrence of a duplicate. If the value 5 appears more than once, I don't want the value at all. For example, if I have something like this:

### A

1

2

2

3

4

3

I ONLY want the values of 1 and 4, because they only appear once. I'd like every other value deleted, or to have only the values like 1 and 4 appear in another column.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Work on a copy as the following deletes records from source data. In B1 (adjust `90000` to suit):

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A$90000;A1)>1
```

and copy down to suit. Filter A:B, select `1` for ColumnB and delete the selected rows. Change filter to select All.